# What are unique tips for giving a 15-minute defense presentation about your research study?

Tags: presentation, defense

Tomorrow will be my final defense presentation. How do I make sure that everything will go as planned? Any unique tips from any aspects of the presentation that you can give me?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Which country are you in? Which field of study?

Comment: @JW, Philippines. I am still a Grade 12 Senior High School student conducting quantitative research about Vaccine Hesitancy.

Comment: @AidreCabrera this website is specifically for academia, so university/college education. High school questions are [outside of the scope](https://academia.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) ([Read here about why this is the case](https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2059/why-is-academia-only-for-higher-education)) of this community.  Did you perform your research in an academic institution or is this otherwise related to university education?

Comment: Who is the audience, and will you be questioned afterwards?

Comment: @Buffy, only three defense panelists. Yes, I will be questioned afterward.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unique tips? There is much online helpful advice on this so it may be hard to find a *unique* tip.

Nevertheless, my personal reaction to your question is that “defense”, although a conventional academic concept, starts a presenter off on the wrong foot. It conditions us to think of the presentation as somehow adversarial, which it need not be.

The more mature approach is to assume that the audience is first interested in what you have to say, second sympathetic to your task, and third has the job of commending the good and advising about the less good.

Of course there are a few irritating people who may be over-critical, or who wish to exhibit their own cleverness or dominance. They are not central to a positive approach and should merely be handled courteously and objectively, standing your ground where you feel yourself to be correct, and giving way with thanks where they are correct.